# $httpBackend does not mock $.ajax(...) calls

Tags: jquery, angularjs, httpbackend, angular-mock, angularjs-ngmock

Trying to create a mock for $.ajax calls using $httpBackend.

The below mocking snippet worked fine for worked fine with `$http.get('/phones')`

```
$httpBackend.whenGET('/phones')
```

But when tried to use the same for

```
$.ajax({
       url: '/phones',
       type: 'GET'
})
```

This threw a 404 error for the '/phones' ajax call.

Jsfiddler link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/goksean/0hwswjpv/1/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the first line of the [`$httpBackend` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) states, `$httpBackend` is a

> Fake HTTP backend implementation suitable for unit testing applications that use the `$http` service.

If you don't use the `$http` service, then `$httpBackend` will not know about the request, and hence will not be able to intercept it or mock a response.

You should always use `$http` - there's no reason to use `$.ajax` in an angular app.